# how to change "follow" font in twitter icon using css?

Tags: html, css

i can't change my icon font "follow" on my footer.

```html
    <!--footer-->
    <footer>
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; 2020 | All Rights Reserved by <a href="https://twitter.com/gigihhimself">Gigih
                            Pratama</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/gigihhimself" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Follow</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!--end footer-->
```

[i can't change my icon font "follow" on my footer. help me with CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFFs8.jpg)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you be more specific? Changing color? Font size?

Comment: it's solved. thanks for your effort. i appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

There is a css property `font-family`, you can set any `font-family` using that. In your case - you want to change the font-family of `follow`. Just give a class name to your `a` tag and set `font-family` for this class.

```css
.follow {
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
       <a href="https://twitter.com/gigihhimself" class="btn btn-primary follow"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Follow</a>
    </div>
</div>
```